# Run a Exe from another exe

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe7

I want to execute one exe from another exe. but the other exe can not run if first exe is running.

So i want to run the exe and exit from the application before the second exe gets executed.

Any help on this.

Comment: What prevents you from simply executing them in order from your shell? Have you tried anything yet? What research have you located?

Comment: First exe should execute second exe . . but if second exe gets executed and it finds the first exe running then it will exit. i want to avoid that.

Comment: i tried it using bat file

Comment: i run a bat file in which it will wait until first exe is terminated. and after it get terminated i execute other exe from the bat file. this woe=rks but i dont want to add another file. so i am asking for any other clue.

Comment: You don't have much of a choice. You haven't stated your requirements very precisely so `exec` _may_ help (it depends on what you really mean by "the other exe can not run if first exe is running") but, otherwise, you need the calling environment to handle this and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: What OS are you using or do you want it to be portable?

Comment: A simple way would be to have both executables attempt to open (exclusively) the same (arbitrary) file. But David's solution is the robust way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a third application, which you launch from your first app. The third one checks to be sure the first one has terminated, then launches the second app and terminates itself. I have had to do this in the past; it works fine.

Comment: That's no different from his batch file solution except for being _less_ flexible.

Comment: I disagree. It's more portable, and does not depend on any particular batch processor.

Comment: No, it's less portable, because you have to rebuild it for every platform. Batch scripts are text files that you can take with you to practically any UNIX (Linux, Mac) and even run on Windows under MSYS or Cygwin. It doesn't get any more portable than that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly how it is done in Windows, but I think that the general guidelines are the same between linux and windows:

You need to fork a child process, in Linux this is done using fork() function, in Windows I think you can use CreateProcess().
In this child process, you need to call one of the *exec* functions which changes the code of this child process to the code of any executable that you can specify as a parameter to the exec function.

The code, thus, should be something like this pseudo-code:

```
c= CreateProcess()
if (c == child)
{
    exec("My other executable.exe")
}
```

This is the general procedure, but you need to figure out the syntax

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a process to sit in the middle if you are not allowed to have the two main processes executing simultaneously. Which means that you need three processes in total. The two main processes, A and C, and the broker in the middle, B. Here's how it goes down:

- Process A executes.
- Process A starts process B passing in its process
  handle.
- Process A terminates.
- Process B waits on process handle for process A. That becomes signaled when process A has terminated.
- Process B starts process C.
- Process B terminates.

I'm assuming that you already know how to create processes, pass arguments to process, duplicate handles, wait on handles and so on.